# Using jQuery .find to locate matching LI

Tags: jquery, html

I have a variable that generates a random number between 1 and 5.

I have an unordered list with the below structure

```
<ul id="list-items">
    <li id="1"></li>
    <li id="2"></li>
    <li id="3"></li>
    <li id="4"></li>
    <li id="5"></li>
</ul>
```

I want to append a class to the list item that relates to the random generated variable. So far i have this -

```
var random_variable = 1;

if (("#list-items").find("#"+random_variable+"").length ) {
    $(this).addClass("selected");
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like randomized at all in your posted HTML markup and because IDs must be unique on document context, i guess you don't really want true randomized number as ID

Comment: Just a quick "best practices" - I would discourage you from using only numbers as element id's.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is that `this` isn't scoped to the element in your conditional statement. In this case, `this` refers to the global `window` object, which is why it isn't working.

You can remove the conditional statement and simplify your code to the following:

```
$('#list-items #' + random_variable).addClass("selected");
```

There is no need to check if the element exists, because if it doesn't the class just isn't added.

Comment: Or just: $(`#' + random_variable).addClass("selected");`

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to use .find(). Since you're using numbers as an id, just use that as the selector in JQuery. Just be careful when you generate the random that it falls within the bounds of your elements, or else nothing will happen.

```
$(function(){
var random = 1;
var li = '#'+random;
$(li).addclass(//stuff);
});
```